# Reading HDF5 data sets with the NetCDF Java library

Tags: java, dataset, hdf5, netcdf

We've been given some files in HDF5 that contain *data sets*, tabular data in which each column is named and may be of a distinct data type (e.g. "author" of type string, "count" of type unsigned integer, etc.) The only pure-Java (i.e. non-JNI) library I can find for reading HDF5 is NetCDF.

It appears that I can read a single column of data from an HDF5 data set using a NetCDF `Variable`. But is there no way to read in an entire table of data from a data set? Are HDF5 data sets to NetCDF merely collections of variables with single-dimensioned array values rather than tables?

*Edit: Let me explain further.* If I open up one of the HDF5 files in HDFView 2.9, navigate to an item of "HDF5 Compound Dataset", and select "Open", a nice little table appears in which the "variables" are shown as column headers and each row is marked by an index. For sake of example let's say there is a "Foo" column of type integer-32-signed and a "Bar" column of type string.

But the NetCDF API for loading data from this "compound dataset" doesn't seem to resemble tabular data at all. I can ask to load an entire array of "variable" named "Foo", and that "variable" seems to be independent of the "Bar" variable. Does this mean that the "Foo" and "Bar" variables can be arrays of different lengths?

In a table I would expect to be able to access things on a row-by-row basis. Could I say "give me an array with all values things in row 5?" OK, so there's an issue with primitive values and boxing and such, but could I request that the underlying bytes of an entire row be returned? Could I say, "give me the value in row 5 in column 'Foo' as an integer"? Perhaps you say that what I'm really wanting to request is element 5 in the "Foo" array. So I'm back to my original question: **Question 1.** Is the NetCDF API for data sets merely access to a group of completely unrelated variables (with potentially separate array lengths, etc.), or is there some API that allows access to this data as a true table?

If you still don't understand the distinction between a tabular view and a list of variables, consider this related question: **Question 2.** How can I find the number of rows in a data set table? Am I forced to iterate all the variables in a data set and find the maximum of the length of each array?

Since I'm finding array lengths of variables, that brings up yet another issue: **Question 3.** How can I find the length of a variable in a data set without reading the entire array? If I use `netCDFFile.findVariable("/some/path/dataset.variable").getSize()`, this simply returns the value `1`. It's not until I actually read the entire array (potentially many megabytes!) using `netCDFVariable.read().getSize()` that I get the correct length! Isn't there a more efficient way?

*Answer:* The answer turns out to be an elaboration on [John Caron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16319887/421049). For some reason each variable (column) thinks that it is variable-length, even though its parent structure (dataset/table) is fixed length. To work with a group of variables in a more tabular fashion, get a reference to the parent `Structure` (itself a `Variable`), and ask for its size. The `Structure.getSize()` value will correctly indicate the length of each variable---even though each `Variable.getSize()` will return `1`.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if someone voting down a serious question would take the time to explain why they did such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 1. Is the NetCDF API for data sets merely access to a group
>   of completely unrelated variables (with potentially separate array
>   lengths, etc.), or is there some API that allows access to this data
>   as a true table?

NetCDF-Java is a low level library, on which other apps build specific interfaces. HDFView is such an app, though not built on NetCDF-Java. You could have a look at ToolsUI from Unidata, it has some functionality for examining data from Structures, though no documentation.

> Question 2. How can I find the number of rows in a data set table? Am
>   I forced to iterate all the variables in a data set and find the
>   maximum of the length of each array?

A Structure will probably look like

```
Structure {
  float fld1;
  int fld2;
  ...
} sname (200);
```

So its an array (in this example, 1D) of structure data (aka compound in HDF5).
So the number of rows is

```
Varible snameV = ncfile.findVariable("sname");
long nrows = snameV.getSize();
```

> Question 3. How can I find the length of a variable in a data set
>   without reading the entire array? If I use
>   netCDFFile.findVariable("/some/path/dataset.variable").getSize(), this
>   simply returns the value 1. It's not until I actually read the entire
>   array (potentially many megabytes!) using
>   netCDFVariable.read().getSize()

If its a variable length array, then you have:

```
Structure {
  float fld1;
  int fld2;
  ...
} sname (*);
```

where '*' means "variable length dimension". Then theres no way to find out the length without reading. Its a 'feature' of the HDF5 format, I think.

Comment: Some things are still unclear. **Is the structured data stored as an array of structured values, or is it stored as a single structured values of various arrays?** Related to that question, **Can each variable in a structure have an array of different length?** Can `fld1` above have a length 5, and `fld2` have a length 8, for example?

Comment: Ah, this is becoming clearer to me now. What you may not have understood from my question is that the `Variable` representing e.g. `fld1` in NetCDF claims that it is variable-length, _even though the parent structure `sname` is fixed length!_ That's what threw me off and why I kept asking if there was a way to treat the entire data set more like a table. In fact if I get a reference to the variable's parent `Structure`, its `structure.getShape()[0]` returns the correct length of all the child variables---I don't know why each individual variable thinks it is variable-length and returns 1.

Answer (score 0):

The NetCDF-Java will give you access to all the data in an HDF5 file. If not, its a bug and we will fix.

Yes, a dataset in HDF5 == Variable in netCDF.

If the dataset is of "compound" type in HDF5, it will be a "structure" in netCDF-Java.

Cant be more specific unless I can get the actual file.

John

Comment: I don't think you understood what I was asking. I've updated the original question to try to make it clearer. There are now three clearly identified questions. Let me know if the issue is clearer now.